# Example Public Data in FHIR Format

Tags: health-informatics, data, fhir

Can you please link to real/large public dataset in [FHIR](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/overview.html) format?

For example, if I want to download real sequence data I can find it at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE44931 and if I want to find data in BigQuery there are lots of examples at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data.

I've poked around at ncbi.nlm.nih.gov, nlm.nih.gov, clinicaltrials.gov, browse.welch.jhmi.edu/datasets/other-repositories, and various google searches and haven't found anything except for tiny samples like http://docs.smarthealthit.org/dstu2-examples/examples/clinicalimpression-example.canonical.json.

I'm looking for a large real dataset to experiment doing calculations in the FHIR format.

Comment: Welcome JDeMatteo. Our sister-site [bioinformatics.se] may interest you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Large artificial dataset

There is a large synthetic dataset of fake electronic health records available at [Synthetic Mass](https://synthea.mitre.org/). It's not a real dataset, but it's supposed to mirror many of the properties of a large health system in the US state of Massachusetts. You need to register for a free account to get an API key.

##### FHIR representations of publicly available de-identified datasets

The [Medical Information Mart for Intensive Care (MIMIC)](https://mimic.mit.edu/docs/about/) is a famously publicly available de-identified electronic health record (EHR) dataset. It may or may not have data for your purposes, but it is available. There has apparently been some work to provide a [FHIR representation of MIMIC](https://physionet.org/content/mimic-iv-fhir-demo/2.0/). Theoretically it was supposed to be available at fhir.mimic.mit.edu. However, that doesn't currently seem to work. The [source code is available on GitHub](https://github.com/kind-lab/mimic-fhir), so you could attempt to host it yourself if you were so inclined.

#### Why aren't there real datasets?

1. **EHR data is highly sensitive private information.** Very few people are going to agree to have their intensely personal information revealed to the public. Even if participants did provide informed consent, publicly releasing EHR data would pose a serious ethical risk for participants because it would place them at risk for identity theft (Kushida et al 2012. PMCID [6502465](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6502465/)).
2. **De-identifying EHR data is extremely challenging**. Computer scientists often suggest that you can just "de-identify" the EHR data. However, this is extremely challenging (Kushida et al 2012. PMCID [6502465](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6502465/)). US law provides a ["safe harbor"](https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/privacy/special-topics/de-identification/index.html#safeharborguidance) definition of what must be removed from private health information to render it de-identified. Trying to automatically remove these elements from unstructured clinical text, for example, is nearly impossible and is the subject of considerable ongoing research.
3. **Health systems have no incentives to provide the data**. Comprehensive data sets contained in EHRs are highly valuable (monetarily) resources ([Vezyridis et al 2017](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/2053951716688490)). Thus, large health systems have no incentive to give away their valuable data to the public when [they can charge companies in the private sector](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3453818/yes-googles-using-your-healthcare-data-and-its-not-alone.html).